# Ruby: How to post a file via HTTP as multipart/form-data?

Tags: ruby, http, post

I want to do an HTTP POST that looks like an HMTL form posted from a browser. Specifically, post some text fields and a file field.

Posting text fields is straightforward, there's an example right there in the net/http rdocs, but I can't figure out how to post a file along with it.

Net::HTTP doesn't look like the best idea. [curb](http://curb.rubyforge.org/) is looking good.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I like [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client). It encapsulates net/http with cool features like multipart form data:

```
require 'rest_client'
RestClient.post('http://localhost:3000/foo', 
  :name_of_file_param => File.new('/path/to/file'))
```

It also supports streaming.

`gem install rest-client` will get you started.

Comment: I take that back, file uploads now work. Problem I'm having now is the server gives a 302 and the rest-client follows the RFC (which no browser does) and throws an exception (since browsers are supposed to warn about this behavior). THe other alternative is curb but I've never had any luck installing curb in windows.

Comment: The API has changed a little since this was first posted, multipart now is invoked like:

RestClient.post 'http://localhost:3000/foo', :upload => File.new('/path/tofile'))

See http://github.com/archiloque/rest-client for more details.

Comment: rest_client does not support supplying request headers. Many REST applications require/expect specific type of headers so rest client won't work in that case. For example JIRA requires a token X-Atlassian-Token.

Comment: Is it possible to get the file upload progress? e.g. 40% is uploaded.

Comment: +1 for adding the `gem install rest-client` and `require 'rest_client'` parts.  That info is left off of too many ruby examples.

Comment: In response to @onknows comment, `rest-client` _does_ now support user-defined request headers. As far as I can tell, that's been in place since at least `1.5.0`, which was released on Apr 30, 2010.

Answer (score 47):

Another one using only standard libraries:

```
uri = URI('https://some.end.point/some/path')
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request['Authorization'] = 'If you need some headers'
form_data = [['photos', photo.tempfile]] # or File.open() in case of local file

request.set_form form_data, 'multipart/form-data'
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http| # pay attention to use_ssl if you need it
  http.request(request)
end
```

Tried a lot of approaches but only this was worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for this. One minor point, line 1 should be:

`uri = URI('https://some.end.point/some/path')`

That way you can call `uri.port` and `uri.host` without error later on.

Comment: one minor change, if not tempfile and you want to upload a file from your disc, 
you should use `File.open` not `File.read`

Comment: most of the cases a filename is required, this is the form how I added:
 form_data = [['file', File.read(file_name), {filename: file_name}]]

Comment: this is the correct answer. people should stop using wrapper gems when possible and go back to the basics.

Comment: Finally, I found some code that actually works!!! Thanks

Comment: If you need to send params on a `POST` request that is also sending multipart data, you would add it to the URL, example: `'https://some.end.point/some/path?foo=bar'`. Also this is the best solution, no need to install gems for every problem.

Comment: Don't forget the `set_form` parameter has to be an array of arrays - a `Hash` will raise while encoding the request. If you have a `Hash` of parameters and want to add a local file, `request.set_form (params.to_a + [['file', File.new('./my_local_file')]]), 'multipart/form-data'` will work.

Answer (score 41):

I can't say enough good things about Nick Sieger's multipart-post library.

It adds support for multipart posting directly to Net::HTTP, removing your need to manually worry about boundaries or big libraries that may have different goals than your own.

Here is a little example on how to use it from the [README](http://github.com/nicksieger/multipart-post/blob/master/README.txt):

```
require 'net/http/post/multipart'

url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/upload')
File.open("./image.jpg") do |jpg|
  req = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new url.path,
    "file" => UploadIO.new(jpg, "image/jpeg", "image.jpg")
  res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
    http.request(req)
  end
end
```

You can check out the library here:
http://github.com/nicksieger/multipart-post

or install it with:

```
$ sudo gem install multipart-post
```

If you're connecting via SSL you need to start the connection like this:

```
n = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port) 
n.use_ssl = true
# for debugging dev server
#n.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
res = n.start do |http|
```

Comment: That one did it for me, exactly what I was looking for and exactly what should be included without the need for a gem.   Ruby is so far ahead, yet so far behind.

Comment: awesome, this comes as a God send! used this to monkeypatch the OAuth gem to support file uploads. took me only 5 minutes.

Comment: @matthias I'm trying to upload photo with OAuth gem, but failed. could you give me some example of your monkeypatch?

Comment: The patch was quite specific to my script (quick-and-dirty), but have a look at it and maybe you can some up with a more generic approach (https://gist.github.com/974084)

Comment: Multipart does not support request headers. So if you for example want to use the JIRA REST interface, multipart will just be a waste of valuable time.

Comment: Actually, as of version '1.1.3 / 2011-07-25' headers are supported. initialize a Multipart type object like so: `Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new(url, {filename => file}, { 'custom' => 'header' })`  note that the hash of files is the second param, and the header hash is the third param. Consult the source for multipartable.rb

Answer (score 31):

`curb` looks like a great solution, but in case it doesn't meet your needs, you *can* do it with `Net::HTTP`.  A multipart form post is just a carefully-formatted string with some extra headers.  It seems like every Ruby programmer who needs to do multipart posts ends up writing their own little library for it, which makes me wonder why this functionality isn't built-in.  Maybe it is...  Anyway, for your reading pleasure, I'll go ahead and give my solution here.  This code is based off of examples I found on a couple of blogs, but I regret that I can't find the links anymore.  So I guess I just have to take all the credit for myself...

The module I wrote for this contains one public class, for generating the form data and headers out of a hash of `String` and `File` objects.  So for example, if you wanted to post a form with a string parameter named "title" and a file parameter named "document", you would do the following:

```
#prepare the query
data, headers = Multipart::Post.prepare_query("title" => my_string, "document" => my_file)
```

Then you just do a normal `POST` with `Net::HTTP`:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(upload_uri.host, upload_uri.port)
res = http.start {|con| con.post(upload_uri.path, data, headers) }
```

Or however else you want to do the `POST`.  The point is that `Multipart` returns the data and headers that you need to send.  And that's it!  Simple, right?  Here's the code for the Multipart module (you need the `mime-types` gem):

```
# Takes a hash of string and file parameters and returns a string of text
# formatted to be sent as a multipart form post.
#
# Author:: Cody Brimhall <mailto:brimhall@somuchwit.com>
# Created:: 22 Feb 2008
# License:: Distributed under the terms of the WTFPL (http://www.wtfpl.net/txt/copying/)

require 'rubygems'
require 'mime/types'
require 'cgi'


module Multipart
  VERSION = "1.0.0"

  # Formats a given hash as a multipart form post
  # If a hash value responds to :string or :read messages, then it is
  # interpreted as a file and processed accordingly; otherwise, it is assumed
  # to be a string
  class Post
    # We have to pretend we're a web browser...
    USERAGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/523.10.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10.6"
    BOUNDARY = "0123456789ABLEWASIEREISAWELBA9876543210"
    CONTENT_TYPE = "multipart/form-data; boundary=#{ BOUNDARY }"
    HEADER = { "Content-Type" => CONTENT_TYPE, "User-Agent" => USERAGENT }

    def self.prepare_query(params)
      fp = []

      params.each do |k, v|
        # Are we trying to make a file parameter?
        if v.respond_to?(:path) and v.respond_to?(:read) then
          fp.push(FileParam.new(k, v.path, v.read))
        # We must be trying to make a regular parameter
        else
          fp.push(StringParam.new(k, v))
        end
      end

      # Assemble the request body using the special multipart format
      query = fp.collect {|p| "--" + BOUNDARY + "\r\n" + p.to_multipart }.join("") + "--" + BOUNDARY + "--"
      return query, HEADER
    end
  end

  private

  # Formats a basic string key/value pair for inclusion with a multipart post
  class StringParam
    attr_accessor :k, :v

    def initialize(k, v)
      @k = k
      @v = v
    end

    def to_multipart
      return "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"#{CGI::escape(k)}\"\r\n\r\n#{v}\r\n"
    end
  end

  # Formats the contents of a file or string for inclusion with a multipart
  # form post
  class FileParam
    attr_accessor :k, :filename, :content

    def initialize(k, filename, content)
      @k = k
      @filename = filename
      @content = content
    end

    def to_multipart
      # If we can tell the possible mime-type from the filename, use the
      # first in the list; otherwise, use "application/octet-stream"
      mime_type = MIME::Types.type_for(filename)[0] || MIME::Types["application/octet-stream"][0]
      return "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"#{CGI::escape(k)}\"; filename=\"#{ filename }\"\r\n" +
             "Content-Type: #{ mime_type.simplified }\r\n\r\n#{ content }\r\n"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi! What's the license on this code? Also: It might be nice to add the URL for this post in the comments at the top.  Thanks!

Comment: The code in this post is licensed under the WTFPL (http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/). Enjoy!

Comment: you should not pass the filestream into the initialize call of the `FileParam` class. The assignment in the `to_multipart` method copies the file content again, which is unnecessary! Instead pass only the file descriptor and read from it in `to_multipart`

Comment: This code is GREAT! Because it works. Rest-client and Siegers Multipart-post DON'T support request headers. If you need request headers you will waste a lot of valuable time with rest-client and Siegers Multipart post.

Comment: Actually, @Onno, it does now support request headers. See my comment on eric's answer

Comment: seems for newest ruby the answer is obsoleted

Answer (score 19):

Here is my solution after trying other ones available on this post, I'm using it to upload photo on TwitPic:

```
  def upload(photo)
    `curl -F media=@#{photo.path} -F username=#{@username} -F password=#{@password} -F message='#{photo.title}' http://twitpic.com/api/uploadAndPost`
  end
```

Comment: Despite seeming a bit hackish, this is probably the nicest solution for me so big thanks for this suggestion!

Comment: Just a note for the unwary, the media=@... is what makes curl thing that ... is a file and not just a string. A bit confusing with ruby syntax, but @#{photo.path} is not the same as #{@photo.path}.

This solution is one of the best imho.

Comment: This looks nice but if your @username contains "foo && rm -rf /", this gets pretty bad :-P

Answer (score 11):

Fast forward to 2017, `ruby` `stdlib` `net/http` has this built-in since 1.9.3

> Net::HTTPRequest#set_form): Added to support both application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data.

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html#method-i-set_form

We can even use `IO` which does not support `:size` to stream the form data.

Hoping that this answer can really help someone :)

P.S. I only tested this in ruby 2.3.1

Answer (score 7):

Ok, here's a simple example using curb.

```
require 'yaml'
require 'curb'

# prepare post data
post_data = fields_hash.map { |k, v| Curl::PostField.content(k, v.to_s) }
post_data << Curl::PostField.file('file', '/path/to/file'), 

# post
c = Curl::Easy.new('http://localhost:3000/foo')
c.multipart_form_post = true
c.http_post(post_data)

# print response
y [c.response_code, c.body_str]
```

Answer (score 3):

restclient did not work for me until I overrode create_file_field in RestClient::Payload::Multipart.

It was creating a **'Content-Disposition: multipart/form-data'** in each part where it should be **‘Content-Disposition: form-data’**.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt

My fork is here if you need it: git@github.com:kcrawford/rest-client.git

Comment: This is fixed in the latest restclient.

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution with NetHttp has a drawback that is when posting big files it loads the whole file into memory first.

After playing a bit with it I came up with the following solution:

```
class Multipart

  def initialize( file_names )
    @file_names = file_names
  end

  def post( to_url )
    boundary = '----RubyMultipartClient' + rand(1000000).to_s + 'ZZZZZ'

    parts = []
    streams = []
    @file_names.each do |param_name, filepath|
      pos = filepath.rindex('/')
      filename = filepath[pos + 1, filepath.length - pos]
      parts << StringPart.new ( "--" + boundary + "\r\n" +
      "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + param_name.to_s + "\"; filename=\"" + filename + "\"\r\n" +
      "Content-Type: video/x-msvideo\r\n\r\n")
      stream = File.open(filepath, "rb")
      streams << stream
      parts << StreamPart.new (stream, File.size(filepath))
    end
    parts << StringPart.new ( "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n" )

    post_stream = MultipartStream.new( parts )

    url = URI.parse( to_url )
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
    req.content_length = post_stream.size
    req.content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary
    req.body_stream = post_stream
    res = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start {|http| http.request(req) }

    streams.each do |stream|
      stream.close();
    end

    res
  end

end

class StreamPart
  def initialize( stream, size )
    @stream, @size = stream, size
  end

  def size
    @size
  end

  def read ( offset, how_much )
    @stream.read ( how_much )
  end
end

class StringPart
  def initialize ( str )
    @str = str
  end

  def size
    @str.length
  end

  def read ( offset, how_much )
    @str[offset, how_much]
  end
end

class MultipartStream
  def initialize( parts )
    @parts = parts
    @part_no = 0;
    @part_offset = 0;
  end

  def size
    total = 0
    @parts.each do |part|
      total += part.size
    end
    total
  end

  def read ( how_much )

    if @part_no >= @parts.size
      return nil;
    end

    how_much_current_part = @parts[@part_no].size - @part_offset

    how_much_current_part = if how_much_current_part > how_much
      how_much
    else
      how_much_current_part
    end

    how_much_next_part = how_much - how_much_current_part

    current_part = @parts[@part_no].read(@part_offset, how_much_current_part )

    if how_much_next_part > 0
      @part_no += 1
      @part_offset = 0
      next_part = read ( how_much_next_part  )
      current_part + if next_part
        next_part
      else
        ''
      end
    else
      @part_offset += how_much_current_part
      current_part
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is class StreamPart?

Answer (score 1):

there's also nick sieger's [multipart-post](http://github.com/nicksieger/multipart-post) to add to the long list of possible solutions.

Comment: multipart-post does not support request headers.

Comment: Actually, @Onno, it does now support request headers. See my comment on eric's answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (need to post to jboss web server). Curb works fine for me, except that it caused ruby to crash (ruby 1.8.7 on ubuntu 8.10) when I use session variables in the code.

I dig into the rest-client docs, could not find indication of multipart support. I tried the rest-client examples above but jboss said the http post is not multipart.

Answer (score 0):

The multipart-post gem works pretty well with Rails 4 Net::HTTP, no other special gem

```
def model_params
  require_params = params.require(:model).permit(:param_one, :param_two, :param_three, :avatar)
  require_params[:avatar] = model_params[:avatar].present? ? UploadIO.new(model_params[:avatar].tempfile, model_params[:avatar].content_type, model_params[:avatar].original_filename) : nil
  require_params
end

require 'net/http/post/multipart'

url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/upload')
Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new(url, model_params)
  key = "authorization_key"
  req.add_field("Authorization", key) #add to Headers
  http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == "https")
  http.request(req)
end
```

https://github.com/Feuda/multipart-post/tree/patch-1

Answer (score 0):

Using [http.rb](https://github.com/httprb/http) gem:

```
HTTP.post("https://here-you-go.com/upload",
          form: {
            file: HTTP::FormData::File.new(file_path)
          })
```

[Details](https://github.com/httprb/http/wiki/Passing-Parameters#file-uploads-via-form-data)

Answer (score 0):

Haha, seems like doing this without a gem is a well guarded secret.

I used HTTParty gem:

```
HTTParty.post(
  'http://localhost:3000/user',
  body: {
    name: 'Foo Bar',
    email: 'example@email.com',
    avatar: File.open('/full/path/to/avatar.jpg')
  }
)
```

https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/multipart.rb

https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

```
gem install httparty
```