# Upload a file with carrierwave

Tags: ruby, upload, carrierwave

First of all, I'm a real beginner in RoR, so excuse the simplicity of the question.
I am trying to upload a file with POST parameters. The form is basic : A text_field (not related with the file) and a file_field. I am using CarrierWave gem. The idea is to get the choosen file from the user and upload it in a local folder.

I can't manage to upload the file and I don't understand why. Someone has an idea ?

My code :

view/home/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @home, :url => {:action => 'uploadFile'}, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|%>
<div class="field">
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.label :campagne, "Nom de la campagne : " %></td>
    <td><%= text_field_tag :campagne %></td>
  </tr>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.label :fichier, "Fichier de numéros : " %></td>
    <td><%= f.file_field :fichier %></td>
  </tr>
</div>
</table>
<p><%= f.submit "Charger le fichier"%></p>  
<% end %>
```

home_controller :

```
def index
    self.new
    render :file => 'app\views\home\index.html.erb'
end

def new
    @home = Home.new(params[:fichier])

end

def uploadFile
    #campagne = params[:campagne]
    #chemin = params[:numeros]
    #post = DataFile.save(params[:upload])
    #render :text => "Nom de la capagne : #{campagne} et Chemin du fichier : #{chemin}"
    #post = DataFile.save(params[:upload])
    require "carrierwave"

    # Stockage du fichier à l'aide de CarrierWave
    stockage = FichierUploader.new
    stockage.store!(params[:fichier])

    render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully " + " Campagne : " + params[:campagne] + " Fichier : " + params[:fichier].to_s
end
```

routes.rb :

```
match "home" => "home#index"
match "home/uploadFile" => "home#uploadFile"

resources :home
get 'home/uploadFile'
post 'home/uploadFile'
```

Comment: what mime type file are you trying to upload?

Comment: It is just a simple text file (MIME : text/plain)

Comment: Nobody has an anwer ? :/

Comment: oops sorry didn't notice your reply. If its simple text file, you don't need to use such fancy gems to upload file you can roll your own.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390993/uploading-a-file-to-a-website-with-ruby-rails might help you

Comment: Thx for your help, I finally used the "classic" upload without gem.