# Ruby On Rails: ActiveResource and file uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, activeresource

Does anyone have experience with ActiveResource and file uploads?
I have an Adobe Air desktop application which communicates with my Rails driven website's web services.

I'd like to post files to the server but I'm not entirely sure if I could do this with ActiveResource. Also, I'm having some concerns since I've read somewhere that AR cannot handle multipart requests. Not too promising.

Anyone have ideas how to do this? A link or a blog post maybe?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottomline is, activeresource does not handle multiparts.

Options could be to use:
 - Curb: Curl for ruby
 - Code your own handler
 - rest-client (git fork with multipart streaming)
 - Use httpclient with multipart posts

These links will give you inspiration:

- http://www.nabble.com/Rest-client-posting-multipart-to-rails-2-td20731160.html
- [Ruby: How to post a file via HTTP as multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184178/ruby-how-to-post-a-file-via-http-as-multipart-form-data/184303)
- http://github.com/technoweenie/rest-client/tree/multipart_streaming
- http://github.com/adamwiggins/rest-client/tree/master
- http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/141-How-to-perform-a-file-upload-multipart-post-with-Ruby
- http://dev.ctor.org/http-access2