# Ruby Oauth File upload/Multipart POST request

Tags: ruby, rest, oauth, oauth-ruby

I've been looking at this for a couple of days now and haven't
found a solution. Is there a way to upload a file using OAuth-Ruby?

I am working with a REST system that protects their resource with oauth. I am building a test tool using ruby and oauth-ruby to make it easier to upload test data to the system. But I can't get around to upload files to the resources.

When I send a normal request, everything works but adding a file as a
parameter makes the signature invalid.

Example:

```
 @access_token.post("http://.../imageresource", {:name=>"awesome cat"}, {'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'})
```

works but gives me:

```
 <error>
    <message>images/POST: Request has no file data</message>
 </error>
```

I am not sure how to add a file to the post.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks,

Comment: @the-elite-gentleman Oauth is used for authorization not authentication. From oauth.net - "An open protocol to allow secure API authorization  in a simple and standard method from desktop and web applications."
I have updated the question to clarify

Comment: correct....sorry, I tend to confuse authentication and authorization.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Ruby person, but are you adding file data to your POST request? Can you check the HTTP Post request to see if your file data has been mimed and send to Http post? (or am I not clear?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old but I'm looking to do this too, [this](https://gist.github.com/1075327) looks like it could do the trick.

Actually there's a question [ruby-how-to-post-a-file-via-http-as-multipart-form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184178/ruby-how-to-post-a-file-via-http-as-multipart-form-data/2603805#2603805)  that has an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is either impossible to do with the `oauth` gem or exceedingly difficult.  Either way, I don't know of any way to do it using that gem.

It can be done trivially with my `signet` gem as long as you have a handy way to construct a valid multipart request body.  The construction of such a request body is out-of-scope of an OAuth gem, but should be pretty easy to do with most HTTP clients.  The `httpadapter` gem can then translate the request into a form that `signet` can sign.  Let me know if your preferred HTTP client isn't supported by `httpadapter` and I'll get that resolved immediately.

See the second example on the [`fetch_protected_resource`](http://signet.rubyforge.org/api/Signet/OAuth1/Client.html#fetch_protected_resource-instance_method) method to get an idea for how this might be done.

Comment: Hi Bob! Sound Great and I will look into it. I haven't been working with Ruby and Oauth for a while now so it might take a while before I go round looking at it, but from what I can read here it sounds very interesting. Promise to get back to you. (And If I don't just send a message in a few weeks, that'll get me moving)