# Is there anyway to use the Imageshack API without PHP?

Tags: html, xml, api, image, cross-domain

If I use the ImageShack API just in a form like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php">
<p><input type="file" name="fileupload"></p>
<p><input type="text" name="key" value="Your_Developer_Key"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Go"></p>
</form>
```

the browser gets taken to an XML doc, which has the image URL, but is no use because I'm no longer on my site. I've tried loading it in an iFrame and that works, but I can't access it because it's cross-domain.

A Http Post in jquery won't work because I can't send a file in it. I don't know any PHP so using that would take lots of time to learn & setup etc. Do I have any other options?

Comment: Do you know *any* server-side language? You don't have to use php - for example .NET, jsp eller python could also do the job.

Comment: @Thomas - So far the only web-related stuff I know is Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Ruby on Rails runs at the server side. So how about using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention you know Ruby on Rails.

Posting a file with Ruby is rather simple. See: [Ruby: How to post a file via HTTP as multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184178/ruby-how-to-post-a-file-via-http-as-multipart-form-data)