# How can I post xml data using net/http that also has data in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, http, post, net-http

I am working with an api that requires me to post xml to url such as someapi.com?userID=123.  Thus far, I have tried this (assume the xml is composed already in the xml variable):

```
url = URI.parse('http://www.someapi.com/process_leads.asp')
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request.content_type = 'text/xml'
request.body = xml
request.set_form_data({'userID' => '1204'}, ';')
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.request(request)}
```

I am trying to figure out if I can have the userID as form data but also post xml? I am basically supposed to post the xml to http://www.someapi.com/process_leads.asp?userID=1204. Is that possible?

Comment: Should I be using multipart, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184178/ruby-how-to-post-a-file-via-http-as-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would consider using a Http library, e.g. [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)

Example using HTTParty for your request would look something like:

```
HTTParty.post('http://www.someapi.com/process_leads.asp', :query => {:userID => 1024}, :body => xml )
```

the :query option takes a hash of key/values which will be added to the post URL,
the :body is where the xml goes.

NOTE: some api's require the xml to have a name e.g. you may have to do something like

```
:body => "request=#{xml}"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to move to a http library.  I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Don't be afraid... It will make your life easier, and your code smell less.

Comment: Worked perfectly after I banged my head against the wall for hours only to realize I had a simple typo!