# How do I upload a file via Carrierwave over a JSON API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a file-manipulation API in Rails, and I need to be able to access it via a separate gem. The API uses Carrierwave, and that piece works with no trouble. What I don't understand how to do is to take an arbitrary file and deliver it to the API from the gem interface.

Carrierwave takes its files as either the results of `File.open('foo.jpg')` or as a POST from a file field. I'm really not sure what either is doing, though, to serialize the file and send it along.

How do I take the contents of a file and turn that into something I can pass around and post via JSON?

Comment: Do you mean the API receives stuff as JSON instead of form parameters?

Comment: That's right. The API will be receiving things in JSON, as it's meant to support a command-line interface instead of a browser-based interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an HTML form POSTs a file, what actually happens is a special part of HTTP called a multipart request. Effectively, the file gets "attached" to the request.

The question will be answered by what library you are using to POST the JSON to your api. Attaching a file to a request should be fairly commonplace but not all libraries may support it.

[This stack overflow article seems to give some good indications of how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184178/ruby-how-to-post-a-file-via-http-as-multipart-form-data)

Comment: This is a great way to accomplish the things I was trying to accomplish. It sounds like the original question starts with a bad premise - a file wouldn't be serialized to a JSON object at all, but rides in a completely different part of the protocol. In any event, this library gets me off to a great start, and if I get to wondering how it does what it does I can always hit the source code of that. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. Notably, you CAN embed a file in the JSON using base64 encoding or some other ASCII encoding, however I wouldn't recommend that path unless you really need it.