# How do I make a Multipart request without creating files on the hard disk?

Tags: ruby, multipartform-data, multipart

I need to request an http api, the problem is that instead of a common post request where all the parameters are separated by an **&**, they expect a **Multipart** request for each one of the parameters like this:

```
POST /core/eligibility HTTP/1.1 
Host: server_host:server_port 
Content-Length: 2408 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=XbCY 
--XbCY 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“PayloadType“ 
X12_270_Request_005010X279A1 
--XbCY 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“ProcessingMode" 
RealTime 
--XbCY 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“PayloadID" 
e51d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6da6 
--XbCY 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“TimeStamp" 
2007-08-30T10:20:34Z 
--XbCY 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“UserName" 
hospa 
--XbCY 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“Password" 
8y6dt3dd2 
--XbCY 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“SenderID" 
HospitalA 
--XbCY 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“ReceiverID" 
PayerB 
--XbCY 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“CORERuleVersion" 
2.2.0 
--XbCY 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“Payload" 
<contents of file go here -- 1674 bytes long as specified above> 
--XbCY—
```

There is a nice [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184178/ruby-how-to-post-a-file-via-http-as-multipart-form-data) about sending a Multipart request with ruby, the problem is that you have to create a file for each of the parameters, creating like 10 different files for a simple api request is nonsense.

Is there a way to do the same without the need to create a file on disk?

Comment: Is your concern about temporarily creating that number of files because of space, or speed, or something else?

Comment: My concern is having to create 11 temporal files for each one of the api requests I want to make, and besides I had the values already on Strings, it feels ugly to create 11 temporal files to submit 1 api request, and drop those files after the api submit, so I was looking to be able to make a Multipart HTTP Requests wi the values I already had on my variables. And it was hard to find documentation on the subject as well, I was using git://github.com/nicksieger/multipart-post.git until I found this feature on rest-client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is :)

By looking at the gem **[rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/payload.rb)**, I found that there is a nice parameter called **multipart**, when its **true**, all the parameters are sent like a Multipart request.

I.e.:

```
require 'rest-client'
request_params = {
   CORERuleVersion: "value1",
   PayloadType: "value2",
   ProcessingMode: "value3",
   UserName: "value4",
   Password: "value5",
   SenderID: "value6",
   ReceiverID: "value7",
   PayloadID: "value8",
   TimeStamp: Time.now.utc.iso8601,
   Payload: "long_payload",
   multipart: true
}
RestClient.post("http://www.example.com", request_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to tell what your concern is, creating the files because of disk I/O or clutter, or what.

If it's any sort of I/O, you should be able to use Ruby's StringIO class, instead of a regular IO object. Everything is written and read in memory, using strings as buffers.

Comment: My concern is having to create 11 temporal files when I have everything on memory with strings. Can u post a sample on how to do it with StringIO? Thx