# Ruby post a file stream via HTTP as multipart/form-data?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, filestream

Now,I have a need that post a file stream,not a local file.the process is:

client(file) ---> my server  ---->  third party Cloud Storage,the transfer is file stream.
I have found this article:
[Ruby: How to post a file via HTTP as multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184178/ruby-how-to-post-a-file-via-http-as-multipart-form-data)

```
require 'rest_client'
RestClient.post('http://localhost:3000/foo', 
:name_of_file_param => File.new('/path/to/file'))
```

you can see that the `name_of_file_param` is a local file,not stream.

so I want to know ,if this is file stream form the client ,what should I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use any IO object, including a stream, as the parameter:

```
RestClient.post('http://localhost:3000/foo', :name_of_file_param => my_stream)
```

Comment: Thanks,this works.now I can use this upload the local file and a file stream.But now I need to upload a remote file to the  Cloud Storage server,so I must read the remote file to a file stream,I use `open-uri` but this still not work,It seems that the stream format is not right.so what should I do? thanks!

Comment: You should be able to write the result from open-uri to a `Tempfile` or a `StringIO`, then this should again behave like any other IO object.

Comment: yes,you are right,I want to write the result from open-uri to a `StringIO`. but when I use the `open-uri` to transfer the remote file to file stream,the  Cloud Storage return a error that the format is no t right,I think the reason is that the encoding is not `ASCII-8BIT`

Comment: If the file is from user client upload then `render text: params[:file]` will raise an error `"\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8` this shows that the file encoding is `ASCII-8BIT`.But the remote file  `render text: web_contents ` will return messy code like `����JFIF``��C ` so this encoding is  not `ASCII-8BIT` not the same as custom uoload file.Can you tell me why? thanks!

Comment: No idea. Please add a separate question for that and try to explain your problem in more detail. It is a completely different topic.