# How to send a POST request using HTTParty (Net::HTTP) which sends a file to a server

Tags: ruby, http

I cannot find an example of how to perform a POST request to a server and upload a file using HTTParty.
The server (which has an API) expects a file to be uploaded.

The encoding method must be **multipart/form-data**

Thanks.

Comment: Take a loot [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184178/ruby-how-to-post-a-file-via-http-as-multipart-form-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end what I did was using the RestClient library since it implements the **multipart/form-data** Content Type.

Although this library uses internally ruby's standard HTTP::Net library, it creates a way to compensate for the missing feature.

I was in shock when I noticed the standard library of Ruby did not come with such a thing out-of-the box.

For anyone interested in exploring other alternatives to this topic/problem, I also suggest you a look [at here](https://github.com/nicksieger/multipart-post) which is basically a library that gives you the ability to upload files using Net::Http which is nice.

[Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) also allows file upload but I did not test to see how it works so I don't know more than what the documentation mentions about it.